# When will a development version of iPhone app expired?

Tags: iphone, ios

If an app is installed on iPhone via debug run, when will it be expired?

Comment: When your development provisioning profile expires, most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will stop working when its provisioning profile expires. You can look up this date either in Apple's provisioning portal or in Xcode's organizer window (command+shift+2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just as @aroth said

> When your development provisioning profile expires, most likely.

which including Development & Distribution (AppStore, Ad-Hoc) provisioning profile. You can check the expiration time at

> Xcode -> Organizer -> Devices -> Your Device -> Provisioning profiles -> Your Dev provisioning profile -> Expiration

And it also might be a file like `iOS Team Provisioning Profile`. In this case, you don't need to create a development provisioning profile every time for your new App.